# Xcode11で2個目のアプリからデバイスが見つからない？

Tags: xcode

UnityでiOSアプリを開発してまして，Xcodeで実機にビルドしようとしたら，デバイスが見つからないと言われます．
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以前にUnityで作ったiOSアプリは，しっかりとデバイスを認識していて，ビルドも通るのですが，2個目のアプリでは，
なぜか見つかりません．
アプリケーションごとに実機の登録などが必要なのでしょうか？
詳しい方がいましたらどうか．知恵を借して下さい．

バーション
macOSX Catalina 10.15.2
Xocde 11．0
iPhone11 Pro (13.3)
Unity 2019.2

Answer (score 0):

Xcodeをアップデートしたらいけました．
やっぱり最新バージョンが正義！